# Android, DBflow, AsyncTask и подвисание главного потока

Tags: база-данных, android-sdk, android, vkontakte-api, многопоточность

Добрый день! Столкнулся с такой проблемой... Есть ListView, который выводит данные из БД(DBFlow), данные в БД попадают из сети посредством запроса с помощью AsyncTask. В момент подгрузки ГЛАВНЫЙ поток просто подвисает на тот промежуток времени, в который грузятся данные, несмотря на то, что подгрузка происходит через AsyncTask, а такого быть не должно. Уже что только не пытался делать, помогите!

Метод подгрузки из сети в БД:

```
private void download50NextPosts(final long offset) {
        VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(
                VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, GROUP_ID,
                VKApiConst.COUNT, 50,
                VKApiConst.OFFSET, offset,
                VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1)).executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                VKPostArray postsNew = (VKPostArray) response.parsedModel;

                HashMap<Long, String> authorNames = new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    JSONArray groups = response.json.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("groups");
                    for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = groups.getJSONObject(i);
                        authorNames.put(-1 * obj.getLong("id"), obj.getString("name"));
                        //Log.i("GROUPS", "id = " + obj.getLong("id") + "name = " + obj.getString("name"));
                    }

                    JSONArray users = response.json.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("profiles");
                    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = users.getJSONObject(i);
                        authorNames.put(obj.getLong("id"), obj.getString("first_name") + " " + obj.getString("last_name"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < postsNew.size(); i++) {
                    VKApiPost post = postsNew.get(i);
                    VKApiPost repost = new VKApiPost();

                    postBD = new PostTable();

                    //это те параметры, которые относятся только к нашему посту, ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ ЭТО РЕПОСТ
                    postBD.vk_id = post.id;
                    postBD.from_id = post.from_id;
                    postBD.likes = post.likes_count;
                    postBD.user_likes = post.user_likes;
                    postBD.reposts = post.reposts_count;
                    postBD.type = post.post_type;

                    postBD.is_repost = (post.copy_history.size() != 0);

                    // если репост, то выводим его как пост, только с некоторыми изменениями
                    // берем содержимое самого первого поста(коренного)
                    // далее описывать не буду, если нужно будет, надеюсь вспомню какой логике следовал
                    //идет инициализация необходимых оставшихся параметров для репоста или поста
                    if (postBD.is_repost) {
                        repost = post.copy_history.get(post.copy_history.size() - 1);

                        postBD.comment_to_repost = post.text;

                        postBD.setRepostAuthor(authorNames.get((long) repost.from_id));

                        //getPostAuthorNameById(repost.from_id);
                        //postBD.repost_author = postAuthor.toString();

                        postBD.attachment_string = repost.toAttachmentString().toString().replace("wall0", "wall" + repost.from_id);
                        postBD.text = repost.text;
                    } else {
                        postBD.text = post.text;
                        postBD.attachment_string = post.toAttachmentString().toString().replace("wall0", "wall" + post.from_id);
                    }

                    //postBD.insert();
                    postBD.save();

                    if (postBD.is_repost) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < repost.attachments.size(); j++) {
                            //если тип вложений фото
                            if (repost.attachments.get(j).getType().equals(VKApiConst.PHOTO)) {
                                //получение фото из вложений
                                VKApiPhoto photo = (VKApiPhoto) repost.attachments.get(j);

                                PictureTable pictureBD = new PictureTable();

                                //пока что просто сохранение ссылки вместо пути
                                //когда надо будет будем загружать фото и сохранять путь из файлов
                                pictureBD.vk_id = postBD.vk_id;
                                pictureBD.picture_path = photo.photo_604;

                                pictureBD.setPost(postBD);

                                pictureBD.save();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (int j = 0; j < post.attachments.size(); j++) {

                            //если тип вложений фото
                            if (post.attachments.get(j).getType().equals(VKApiConst.PHOTO)) {
                                //получение фото из вложений

                                VKApiPhoto photo = (VKApiPhoto) post.attachments.get(j);

                                PictureTable pictureBD = new PictureTable();

                                //пока что просто сохранение ссылки вместо пути
                                //когда надо будет будем загружать фото и сохранять путь из файлов
                                pictureBD.vk_id = postBD.vk_id;
                                pictureBD.picture_path = photo.photo_604;

                                pictureBD.setPost(postBD);

                                pictureBD.save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                adapterForWall.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("adapter.getCount = ", adapterForWall.getCount() + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
                super.attemptFailed(request, attemptNumber, totalAttempts);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

AsyncTask:

```
private class LoadNewPostsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, PostsAdapter> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            NavigationDrawerHost.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected PostsAdapter doInBackground(Long... params) {
            //выполняется в backgroud thread    
            download50NextPosts(params[0]);
            offset += 50;

            return adapterForWall;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PostsAdapter postAdapter) {
            //adapterForWall.notifyDataSetChanged();

            NavigationDrawerHost.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //выполняется в ui thread
        }
    }
}
```

Немного кода из адаптера:

```
//Адаптер реализовывает BaseAdapter
public PostsAdapter(Context context, String func) {
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.func = func;

    if (!new FlowCursorList<>(false, PostTable.class).isEmpty())
        this.posts = new FlowCursorList<>(false, PostTable.class);
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    //таким запросом = работает, а FlowCursorList<>(false, PostTable.class) нет
    this.posts = new Select().from(PostTable.class).queryCursorList();
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

P.S. Да, знаю, что notifyDataSetChanged() стоит в методе с подгрузкой данных, которая выполняется в backgroud thread, но если её перенести в onPostExecute(), то адаптер вообще не видит изменений, кто знает почему буду рад услышать ответ!

P.P.S. А если адаптер даже и видит изменения, то всё равно подвисает, ХЕЕЕЛП!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем путем долгих исследований выяснилось, что в VKSdk под Android метод executeWithListener() уже асинхронный и выполняется в основном потоке, далее выяснилось, что есть синхронный метод executeSyncWithListener(), его то я теперь и использую в своём AsyncTask